# AUTOINCREMENT primary key for snowflake bulk loading

Tags: primary-key, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bulk-load, alteryx

I would like to upload data into snowflake table. The snowflake table has a primary key field with AUTOINCREMENT.

When I tried to upload data into snowflake without a primary key field, I've received following error message:

> The COPY failed with error: Number of columns in file (2) does not
>   match that of the corresponding table (3), use file format option
>   error_on_column_count_mismatch=false to ignore this error

Does anyone know if I can bulk load data into a table that has an AUTOINCREMENT primary key?

knozawa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the stage file using file format to load your data. I have created sample table like below. First column set autoincrement:

```
-- Create the target table
create or replace table Employee (
  empidnumber autoincrement start 1 increment 1,
  name varchar,
  salary varchar
  );
```

I have staged one sample file into snowflake internal stage to load data into table and I have queried stage file using following [image: Stage query] and then I have executed following copy cmd:

```
copy into mytable (name, salary )from (select $1, $2 from @test/test.csv.gz                                );
```

And it loaded the table with incremented values.

Comment: Thank you! Auto increment PK using bulk load worked when I used "COPY INTO".

Comment: I used ```empidnumber autoincrement start 1 increment 1``` but when I delete the old records the ID dose not starts from 1 , ex. if there were 10 records If I delete this and insert again the ID starts with 11, any suggestions for this?

Comment: Try reset the start value if you want to start from the beginning

Answer (score 3):

The docs have the following example which suggests this can be done:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#include-autoincrement-identity-columns-in-loaded-data

```
-- Omit the sequence column in the COPY statement
copy into mytable (col2, col3)
from (
  select $1, $2
  from @~/myfile.csv.gz t
)
;
```

Could you please try this syntax and see if it works for you?

Comment: Looks like they've updated the COPY statement. I wrote my comment based on old information

Comment: Thank you! Auto increment PK using bulk load worked when I used "COPY INTO".

Answer (score 1):

Create the target table

```
create or replace table mytable (
  col1 number autoincrement start 1 increment 1,
  col2 varchar,
  col3 varchar
  );
```

Stage a data file in the internal user stage

```
put file:///tmp/myfile.csv @~;
```

Query the staged data file

```
select $1, $2 from @~/myfile.csv.gz t;

+-----+-----+
| $1  | $2  |
|-----+-----|
| abc | def |
| ghi | jkl |
| mno | pqr |
| stu | vwx |
+-----+-----+
```

Omit the sequence column in the COPY statement

```
copy into mytable (col2, col3)
from (
  select $1, $2
  from @~/myfile.csv.gz t
)
;

select * from mytable;

+------+------+------+
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|------+------+------|
|    1 | abc  | def  |
|    2 | ghi  | jkl  |
|    3 | mno  | pqr  |
|    4 | stu  | vwx  |
+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding of **PRIMARY KEY** is different in **SNOWFLAKE**  when compared to **SQL**

syntax for adding primary key with auto increment

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
  NAME VARCHAR(100),
  SALARY VARCHAR(100),
  EMPLOYEE_ID AUTOINCREMENT START 1 INCREMENT 1,
  );
```

**START 1** = STARTING THE PRIMARY KEY AT NUMBER 1 (WE CAN START AT ANY NUMBER WE WANT )
**INCREMENT** = FOR THE ID ADD THE NUMBER 1 TO PREVIOUS EXISTING NUMBER ( WE CAN GIVE ANYTHING WE WANT)